# Breaking monthly data into daily data in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

this question is similar to the one posted here: [Break up monthly data into daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639168/break-up-monthly-data-into-daily)

However, I'm trying to achieve this using Snowflake. Here is some sample data:

```
+--------------------+----------+---------------------------+----------+---------------+--------+
|         ID         | METRIC_C | OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C | REGION_C | METRIC_DATE_C | GOAL_C |
+--------------------+----------+---------------------------+----------+---------------+--------+
| a0c0W00000P180rQAB | MQL      | Buyer: New                | Europe   | 2020-11-01    |    227 |
| a0c0W00000P181UQAR | Won      | Buyer: New                  Europe   | 2020-02-01    |      1 |
| a0c0W00000P180yQAB | SAL      | Buyer: New                | Europe   | 2020-06-01    |     34 |
+--------------------+----------+---------------------------+----------+---------------+--------+
```

Basically, I want the ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C values to be repeating and for there to be date values for the entire month. The goal value should be equally divided by # of days in the month. I can't seem to get the code to work in Snowflake. Here's what I have so far:

```
with cte as
(select ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, METRIC_DATE_C, GOAL_C
 from GOAL_C
 where METRIC_DATE_C > '2019-12-31'
 union all
 select ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, dateadd(d, 1, METRIC_DATE_C) METRIC_DATE_C, GOAL_C
 from cte
 where datediff(m,METRIC_DATE_C,dateadd(d, 1, METRIC_DATE_C))=0
 and METRIC_DATE_C > '2019-12-31'
)
select ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, METRIC_DATE_C, 
       1.0*GOAL_C / count(*) over (partition by ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, METRIC_DATE_C) GOAL_C
from cte
order by 1,2,3,4,5
```

The code doesn't seem to be splitting the month into days. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, just a small tweak for snowflake syntax did the job. 
Here you go:

```
with cte as
(select ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, METRIC_DATE_C, GOAL_C
 from DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TABLE_NM
 where METRIC_DATE_C > '2019-12-31'
 union all
 select ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, dateadd(day, 1, METRIC_DATE_C) METRIC_DATE_C, GOAL_C
 from cte
 where datediff(month,METRIC_DATE_C,dateadd(day, 1, METRIC_DATE_C))=0
 and METRIC_DATE_C > '2019-12-31'
)
select ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, METRIC_DATE_C, 
       1.0*GOAL_C / count(*) over (partition by ID, METRIC_C, OPPORTUNITY_RECORD_TYPE_C, REGION_C, METRIC_DATE_C) GOAL_C
from cte
order by 1,2,3,4,5
;
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! That's a step in the right direction, but not quite what I wanted. It looks like the original Goal value is being repeated for every day in the month, rather than being divided by the # of days in the month. Any ideas on how to get that working?

Comment: Looks like I just had to remove METRIC_DATE_C from the partition by. It's working now. Thanks again for your help!